# How to read multiple check box values,when post the form?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

```html
Code is

$sql2="select *from pageper where userid='$eid'";
    $result_tag= $db->query($sql2);
    while($crow=$db->fetchArray($result_tag)) {
   
   $psql2="select *from pages where apage_id='".$crow['page_id']."'";
    $presult_tag= $db->query($psql2);
    $prow=$db->fetchArray($presult_tag);
    $pname= $prow['page_name'];
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $prow['page_name']; ?></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo 'add['.$prow['apage_id'].']['.$eid.']'; ?>" value="<?php echo ($crow['isadd']==1)?1:0; ?>" <?php if($crow['isadd']==1) echo 'Checked'; ?>></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo 'list['.$prow['apage_id'].']['.$eid.']'; ?>" value="<?php echo ($crow['islist']==1)?1:0; ?>" <?php if($crow['islist']==1) echo 'Checked'; ?>></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo 'edit['.$prow['apage_id'].']['.$eid.']'; ?>" value="<?php echo ($crow['iedit']==1)?1:0; ?>" <?php if($crow['iedit']==1) echo 'Checked'; ?>></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo 'view['.$prow['apage_id'].']['.$eid.']'; ?>" value="<?php echo ($crow['isview']==1)?1:0; ?>" <?php if($crow['isview']==1) echo 'Checked'; ?>></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo 'delete['.$prow['apage_id'].']['.$eid.']'; ?>" value="<?php echo ($crow['isdelete']==1)?1:0; ?>" <?php if($crow['isdelete']==1) echo 'Checked'; ?>></td>
 <input type="hidden" name="eid1" value="<?php echo $eid; ?>">
</tr>
<?php
    }
```

How to read multiple checkbox values which we assign dynamic values?

Please post the answer solution.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Did you try [`serializeArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)?

Comment: OP Care to check answer?

Comment: People may not realize that when using checkboxes in a form, only those that have been checked will appear in the post parameters. Depending on the application, this might cause server side processing to miss some critical information - if, say, add[2] was previously on and the user wants to turn it off.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$("input:checkbox:checked").val();
```

for looping use each

```
$( "input:checkbox:checked").each(function( index ) {
  console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: He wants to do it at server side.

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com then why did he tag the question with jquery

Comment: Hi , he means Server side = PHP , Not client side = jQuery that you posted

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com I dont know php.. I just answered this because the question tagged with jquery

Comment: Hi look he used Only PHP code. If he wanted jQuery code , he would have posted something related to jQuery .And alos he is saying form is `Posted` means at the server side.

Comment: op's only mention of `when post the form` in the title is far from clearly designing server-side. this answer fits here

Comment: $(this).val() tells you what is in the "value" attribute of the element, regardless of the checkbox being on or off. $(this).prop("checked") will tell you if it is checked.

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through the $_POST array:

```
foreach($_POST as $name=>$val) {..
```

Answer (score 0):

Say for checkbox with name add Use PHP code like below .

```
<?php 
if(!empty($_POST)){
    foreach ($_POST['add'] as $single){

        foreach($single as $key=>$val){
            echo "Checked With key=>".$key ."And Val=>".$val;
        }   
    }
} 
?>


<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<form name="frmm" method="post">
<td><input type="checkbox" name="add['first.']['first']" value="first first checked" checked></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="add['first.']['second']" value="first second checked"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="add['first.']['third']" value="first third checked"></td>
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding a reference parameter as a hidden input of the form:

```
<input name="my_eids[]" value="<?php echo $eid ?>"/>
```

You would then look at $_POST['my_eids'] for the keys you need to check the various add/list/edit parameters.

Also note that when working with checkboxes, only the checked inputs will appear in the parameters sent back to the server. Unchecked checkboxes are ignored. This is why you probably want a hidden reference parameter(s) to make this work correctly.